# how can i get button tag value from one class to another class

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone ,what i am doing is i am creating a button for the image to display in imageview.what i need is how can i get bauttontag value in imagepicker.m to imagepickerviewcontroller.m if it is give some sample code pls  thanku

Comment: "imagepicker.m" and "imagepickerviewcontroller.m" are just two filenames, which don't tell us a lot about your situation. Please be specific in describing what you have writtin until now, and what you would want to happen. If possible, share the code, so you could get some directed advice.